# Why $\sum_nA_n(X_n,X_m)=A_m(X_m,X_m)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, orthogonality, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

Why in the following proof $$\sum_nA_n(X_n,X_m)=A_m(X_m,X_m)$$ ?

The author says it's because orthogonality but orthogonality means $(f,g)=\int_a^bfgdx=0$. So how come orthogonality helps to prove it ?

Could someone explain this please?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That's only true if the $A_k$ are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: But why the equality? why the $\sum$ disappear?

Comment: $(X_n,X_m)=0$ whenever $n\ne m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on other answers/comments, observe that
$$
\sum_{n}A_{n}(X_{n}, X_{m}) = A_{1}(X_{1}, X_{m}) + A_{2}(X_{2}, X_{m}) + \ldots + A_{m}(X_{m}, X_{m}) + \ldots
$$
and all of the terms where the index of $A$ is not $m$ are zero. So,
$$
\sum_{n}A_{n}(X_{n}, X_{m}) = 0 + 0 + \ldots + 0 + A_{m}(X_{m}, X_{m}) + 0 +\ldots = A_{m}(X_{m}, X_{m}).
$$

Comment: ah now it's clear, thank you!

Comment: why didn't I expand the sum..

Answer (score 2):

Because $ (X_n,X_m)=0$ if $n\ne m$. That's the orthogonality.

Comment: I know that's the orthogonality

Comment: But I don't see how that  help to understand why $\sum_nA_n(X_n,X_m)=A_m(X_m,X_m)$

Comment: Not sure what you don't understand. All the terms with $n\ne m$ are zero.