# Solution of $\nabla^2u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, alternative-proof

Calculate the Fourier expansion of $u$ for $$\nabla^2u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,\\ y\ge0,0\le x\le L\\ u(0,y)=0=u_x(L,y), u(x,0)=g(x)=x/L$$.

Solution:

By separation of variables, we propose the solution $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$.

After calculations and after applying the conditions I get that  the general solution is $u(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_ne^{\sqrt{(\lambda_n)}y}D_n\sin(\sqrt \lambda_nx),$ where $A_n=\frac{(g(x),X_n(x))}{\Vert X_n\Vert^2}, X_n(x)=\sin(\frac{(n+1/2)\pi}{L}x),\lambda_n=(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2$

I found $A_n$ when I applied the boundary condition $u(x,0)$. Is there a way to find $D_n$ so the solution would be complete?

Or the solution it's fine as it is?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Are there enough boundary conditions here? You need something to decide on the linear combination of $e^{\pm k x}$ to take in the individual terms.

Comment: @Chappers yes I think are enough, the problem was stated like that :) I don't understand your comment about _decide on the linear combination of $e^{\pm kx}$ to take in the individual terms_

Comment: @Winther sorry I though It was enough information to answer my question, I'll update.

Comment: $A_n$ contain $g(x)$ by a theorem seen before

Comment: I would add more details about how you found the solutions because you seem to have several mistakes here. As a reference I find that the solutions are given by
$$u(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(\lambda_n x)(B_n\sinh(\lambda_n y) + C_n\cosh(\lambda_n y))$$
where $\lambda_n = \frac{\pi(n+1/2)}{L}$ and where $C_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L g(x)\sin(\lambda_n x){\rm d}x$. As Chappers pointed out there are not enough boundary conditions to fix the value of $B_n$.

Comment: @Winther I had a typo it was x instead of L in the general solution. How did you find the result $u(x,y)$ ? I mean did you use software or something else?

Comment: @Winther :) no. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760670/why-sum-na-nx-n-x-m-a-mx-m-x-m I applied it in my answer

Comment: @Winther yeah that's what I meant. I checked again my calculation and I don't see the mistake maybe the term $e$ it's somehow  equivalent to the hyperbolic trigonometric functions

Comment: @Winther I don't have the b-term because $\sin(\sqrt\lambda L)=0\implies \sqrt\lambda L=n\pi\implies \lambda=(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78218/discussion-between-isa-and-winther).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of variables gives

$$ X(x) = \sin\left(\beta_n x\right)  $$

Where $ \beta_n = \sqrt{\lambda_n} = (n+\frac12)\frac{\pi }{L}$

Then

$$ Y'' - \beta^2 Y = 0 $$
$$ \implies Y = Ae^{-\beta y} + Be^{\beta y} $$

Since there are two constants, you need two boundary conditions here to determine a solution. Due to the domain, we will assume that $Y(y)$ remains bounded as $y\to\infty$. Hence, $B=0$ and the general solution is

$$ u(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_ne^{-\beta_n y} \sin(\beta_n x) $$

Plugging in the B.C at $y=0$ results in a Fourier series in $x$, which you can use to solve for $A_n$

$$ A_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L g(x)\sin(\beta_n x)\ dx $$

Comment: @Winther Do you mean $\sin$ in the solution $u(x,y)$?

Comment: It's correct actually because of this $u_x(L,y)$

Comment: You are correct, it should be $\sin$. $n<0$ is not necessary as the solution is an odd extension with period $2L$